# AutoBind TypeScript decorator

Tags: object-oriented, typescript, meta-programming

Idea is to have an AutoBind decorator which you could append in front of any method to have it preserve its own `this`, instead of manually binding it when called.

```
function AutoBind(_: any, _2: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const originalMethod: Function = descriptor.value;
    const adjDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor = {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        get() {
            return originalMethod.bind(this);
        },
    };
    return adjDescriptor;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
class DummyClass {
    name = 'John Doe';

    @AutoBind
    dummyMethod() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

const i = new DummyClass();
const button = document.querySelector('button')!;

button.addEventListener('click', i.dummyMethod);
// instead of button.addEventListener('click', i.dummyMethod.bind(this));
```

What do you think of this?

Answer (score 1):

## The idea

So first of all, about the idea. Technically it is nice to auto-bind methods and use them without worrying about the bad `this` instance.

However, can you really ensure that it will always work? Will you use this decorator on all potential methods? What if you (or other developers working with your code) forget to use this decorator, will the typescript notice the issue and report it? If not, then it is not a good idea.

Well, talking about typescript, even if you won't use `AutoBind`, I don't know a good way to always ensure that it will always work. So my recommendation would be to use [eslint](https://eslint.org/) or another similar tool to detect these patterns and show errors. You can setup lint as a git hook to run before each push or run in CI/CD. For example, you can just force to always use the arrow function when passing to callback to always ensure that it will work with [prefer-arrow-callback](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback) plugin.

## Specify return type

Instead to define the variable type, just specify a return type and use inline return - typescript will validate your return value. In most cases it is a good idea to specify return type to function - if return type will be auto inferred, you can accidentally change it without notice.

```
function AutoBind(_: any, _2: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): PropertyDescriptor {
    const originalMethod: Function = descriptor.value;
    return {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        get() {
            return originalMethod.bind(this);
        },
    }
}
```